# TypeError: (0 , h.QueryClient) is not a constructor | react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query, parcel

Getting the below error in react-application production build. Using the Parcel to build the application.

```
react-dom.production.min.js:189 TypeError: (0 , h.QueryClient) is not a constructor
    at TE (App.js:57:23)
    at ji (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
    at Is (react-dom.production.min.js:290:337)
    at Dl (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
    at Al (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
    at Tl (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
    at gl (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
    at yl (react-dom.production.min.js:268:429)
    at B (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
    at MessagePort.Y (scheduler.production.min.js:14:128)
```

Build Command:

```
parcel build --no-content-hash --no-source-maps --dist-dir build manifest.json
```

Code:

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
export default function App() {

  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  return (
    <>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                  <AppRouter />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Library Versions:

```
React Version: 18.2.0
React-Query: 3.39.2
Parcel: 2.7.0
```

Comment: Hi maybe this can help you :
https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/3476

Answer (score 1):

Also, I think that you should update to [**@tanstack/react-query**](https://github.com/TanStack/query)

> (*It's almost the same API for everything except the query keys which need to be in an array*)

By updating my dependencies (React, react-query) I had no problems

Maybe this should solve the problem for you too

Comment: Thanks horhorou!! Updating the react-query to @tanstack/react-query fixed the error. Will check everything else works fine or not. thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Have a nice day